# Determine the velocity and acceleration of the vertex $B$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

1) The bent rod $ABCD$ rotates about the line $AD$ whit a constant angular velocity of $90 rad / s$. Determine the velocity and acceleration of the vertex $B$ when the rod is in the position shown in Figure.

2) Determine the velocity and acceleration of the vertex $B$ assuming now that the angular velocity is of $95rad / s$ decreasing the rate of $380rad / s^2$.

[image]

My attempt was to apply the formula $\vec{v}=\vec{r}\times \vec{\omega}$ but I think it is not valid if the rotation axis is not aligned with any of the axes in the $xyz$ space. Maybe I'm talking nonsense. I was thinking about making a change coordinatas to the rotation axis coincide with the $z$ axis. But it seems very counterproductive and does not seem to be the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: I think $\vec{v}=\vec{r}\times \vec{\omega}$ is perfectly valid. It doesn't depend on whether $\omega$ is aligned to a Cartesian axis. What you do need to find, is the proper $\vec{r}$.

Comment: @Evert In this case would be the  vector $\vec{r}$ is  $\vec{OB}$? And the vector $\vec{\omega}$?

Comment: $\vec{\omega}$ would have the same direction as the rotation, so $\vec{AD}$. And $\vec{r}$ would be the distance relative to that axis, so $\vec{AB}$ (or $\vec{DC}+\vec{CB}$). However you could also calculate the projected distance from $B$ to the axis of rotation, in which case the angle between $\vec{\omega}$ and $\vec{r}$ would be zero so $\vec{r}\times\vec{\omega}$ would equal $\|\vec{r}\|\|\vec{\omega}\|$.

Comment: I usually have it as $\vec{v}_B = \vec{v}_A + \vec{ \omega} \times (\vec{r}_B-\vec{r}_A)$ so I do not get the sign wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your angular velocity vector is

$$ \vec{\omega} = \Omega \frac{ \vec{r}_D - \vec{r}_A }{|\vec{r}_D - \vec{r}_A|} $$

where $\vec{r}_A = (0,0.2,0.12)$, $\vec{r}_D = (0.3,0,0)$, $\vec{r}_B = (0.3,0.2,0.12) $ in meters and $\Omega = 90\;{\rm rad/s}$.

Your velocity kinematics is

$$ \vec{v}_B = \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{r}_B - \vec{r}_A ) $$

And acceleration kinematics

$$ \vec{a}_B = \dot{\vec{\omega}} \times ( \vec{r}_B - \vec{r}_A ) + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{\omega} \times ( \vec{r}_B - \vec{r}_A ) $$
$$  = \dot{\vec{\omega}} \times ( \vec{r}_B - \vec{r}_A ) + \vec{\omega} \times  \vec{v}_B  $$

From here you [plug-and-chug](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plug%20%27n%20chug).

Comment: I'm almost convinced of his answer. But because the direction is $r_D-r_A$ not the $r_A-r_D$?

Comment: OP says line is $A$ to $D$, therefore it is along $\vec{r}_D-\vec{r}_A$.